# If I am a member of multiple networks, how can I force my Mac to connect to the Internet through one specific network?

Tags: macos, network, thunderbolt, internet-sharing

I have a Macbook and a Thunderbolt display. The Thunderbolt display is connected to a network with a very tight firewall. I also have a WiFi connection that is always connected at this location. The WiFi firewall isn't as aggressive and every now and then I need to connect to it to connect to a SOAP web service that operates on a blocked port.

Is there a ways (hotkey or system preference) that I can toggle so that I can remain connected to both networks, but force my MacBook to connect to the internet through the WiFi, rather than the local network?

Currently, I have to disconnect from the Thunderbolt display, and connect back up when I am finished downloading my data. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the network control panel, click the gear at the bottom of the interface list and select "Set Service Order...".  In that dialog, you can move your WiFi above the ethernet display.

[image: Service Order]

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this without having to change between both networks. Connect to both networks. From the command line run these two commands.

```
    sudo route add -default *ipOfEthernetGateway*
```

That will set all traffic to go through the work ethernet link.

```
    sudo route add -host SOAPserver.com *ipOfWIFIGateway*
```

That will set all traffic that needs to go to the SOAP server to go through the WiFi link.

Comment: Thanks Dennis!  The selected answer was best for my case, but it's always nice to have a shell command available!